# I have to write mini project and don't know how to start

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi everyone I need to write mini project and I have no idea where to start or what are the steps. Can someone help me to how to start or even give me steps to what to do?

```
A perspective client has approached your company to write a program to help track
students accessing the school cafeteria.  The client will supply a list of current student
names and ID numbers. The client would like the program to do the following:


 -Allow the student to enter the school ID number when they enter the cafeteria.  
 -Keep track of the students who are currently in the cafeteria.
 -Display student names and when they logged in
 -Display the total number of students who are currently in the cafeteria.
  Allow the student to enter the school ID number when they enter the cafeteria.
 -Keep track of all the students who accessed the cafeteria throughout the day.
 -Display only to authorized cafeteria personal all the students who came
 -in, when they came in, and when they left.
```

Comment: Please make an effort first. Show what you're thinking and have tried. Then ask for help. Please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Attending to your programming lectures would be a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Allow the student to enter the school ID number when they enter the cafeteria.

  *see `raw_input` or `input`*
- Keep track of the students who are currently in the cafeteria.

  *see dictionary (or even list or some other [Data Structure](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html))*
- Display student names and when they logged in

  *see `print` and `time` respectively*
- Display the total number of students who are currently in the cafeteria.

  *see `len`*
- Keep track of all the students who accessed the cafeteria throughout the day.

  *see dictionary (or even list or some other [Data Structure](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html))*
- Display only to authorized cafeteria personal all the students who came

  *see `print` and `raw_input` (or `input` in python3)*
- in, when they came in, and when they left.

  *see `print` and `time` modules, and use your earlier DataStructures*